# Hello World Java tutorial deployNodes failed

Tags: java, gradle, corda

During the ./gradlew deplyNodes command i received this error message.

```
error: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
                                ^
```

I followed all steps in the tutorial.

Comment: Update your question with a link to the tutorial you were using.

Comment: It would be this tutorial: https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-state.html.

Comment: Yes. Joel is right .

Comment: I´m using Ubuntu as my development environment. All CORDA examples worked just fine.

Comment: Rodrigo, if Joel's answer resolved your problem could you please accept it and/or upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug caused by recent changes to the CorDapp Templates. It is being fixed by this PR.

In the meantime, drop this import and use `Arrays.asList()` instead of `ImmutableList.of()`.