# Newbie problems running example cordapp

Tags: gradle, corda

I'm new to Corda, so am following the "Getting started developing CorDapps".
On my MacBook Pro, I have:
- installed the JDK, IntelliJ Community edition and Git, 
- have downloaded the sample project (using git clone) by following Step One)
- created an IntelliJ project (by following Step Two)
but, when following instructions for Deploy the CorDapp locally (using ./gradlew clean deployNodes), I get the following errors:

Task :contracts-java:compileJava FAILED

/Users/samples/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java:5: error: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
                                ^
... and another 3 similar.

I've searched google, gradle and IntelliJ forums, but cannot find anyhting that helps resolve my issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254524/hello-world-java-tutorial-deploynodes-failed), Open `IOUState.java` and:

1. Remove this import: `import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;`
2. Modify `ImmutableList.of(new IOUSchemaV1())` to `Arrays.asList(new IOUSchemaV1())`

Comment: Thanks very much for the link to previous, and the tip for alternatives :-)

Answer (score 0):

The recent 4.4 upgrades have removed the ImmutableList from the dependencies. You could change the `ImmutableList.of` to `Arrays.asList` or `Collections.singletonList` as a workaround.

Thanks for raising this, we will fix it ASAP.

Comment: Thanks very much - i'll upgrade to 4.4.